# Can't get Angular to work in my NodeJS application (using visual studio 2015)?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, visual-studio-2015

For some reason I get this error saying 'angular undefined'. Does anyone have a clue as to why this may be happening? My code is listed below.

I also screenshotted the error I am getting in the browser (chrome) when pressing ctrl + shift + i

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKrBo.png)

29-10-2015: edited code below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">
<head>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="controller">>
       
        <h1>Contact List App</h1>

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Number</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>

        <div>
            <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
            <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
            <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do I need a controller to use basic angular stuff like this? I mean all I need is declared in the html file itself right?

Comment: @mick : Have you checked in the console, network window in the browser ? If you are getting any error, Kindly share that. It could be helpful to get more information. And controller is mandatory for 2 way binding. you should get some error like "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]......................" Have you ?

Comment: I actually got it to work partially. I cannot use the `<script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>`. However it does work when I use a direct https link `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>` to the source itself (which I found on w3schools). 

This is kind of a bummer though since that means I cannot import any controllers in my html files.

Comment: @Sakthi and no I am not getting any errors.. So confusing haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ng-model without a controller, the model ends up being bound to $rootScope, which is a bad idea.

I see in the comments, you do have a controller, so modifying your div tag to:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
```

should do the trick for you.

Also, the controller belongs to your app, which is the BeheerdersAppGoodOne module, so you need to change the ngApp="" to ngApp="BeheerdersAppGoodOne"

Comment: I still can't get it to work though.. I listed my current code in the question.. Could you check it out please?

Comment: Yes, I revised the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some `app.js`? Something like this

```
var App = angular.module('app', []);
App.run([<module_names>], function (<modules>){});
```

Please show more of your code, and look trough angular docs

Comment: My server.js looks like this:

`var express = require('express');
var server = express();

server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var port = 1337;
server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('server listening n port ' + port);
});`

And that is about all I have at the moment (code-wise).

Comment: And I have a controller: `var myApp = angular.module('BeheerdersAppGoodOne', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        console.log("Hello World from controller");
    }]);`.

Comment: What about your context? You have error in console log: cant get `http://localhost:1337/node_modules/angular/angular.js` may be you should change `<script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>` on `<script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>`

Comment: Please try to out yore current context (`console.log`), i think the problem here, or your server does not see `node_modules` resources

Comment: I tested console.log in my server area and index area. Both work.. At first I saw my node_modules wasn't included in my project. But even after including it, it still does not work..

Answer (score 0):

try to edite like this 
**nodejs:**

```
  server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'))
```

**angularjs:**

```
 <script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea. If you did like this, all the files with in that folder will be exposed to the outer world. node_module contains all the server component also. The link should work well without this command, if the angular installed correctly.

Comment: @Sakthi I agree. However I installed angular thorugh the NPM installer and it was the last stable version. So it should work haha. Do you have any ideas as to what it might be?

Comment: @Sakthi i agree,express.static is responsible for serving the static assets of an Express application. and if you don't want to be exposed ,you must link a new angular modules in public folder.

Comment: @Cr : Yes. We should split the client and server side components separately and then we can use express.static function for client side components like CSS, JS, images, etc.,

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the angular CDN and it is all working properly now!